# Accessing RequestContext from global.asax

Tags: model-view-controller

Does anyone know how to get the current RequestContext from the Application_Error event in global.asax?? My problem is that i need to do a redirect, and thereby need to have the url generated using UrlHelper - which takes the aformentioned RequestContext.

Comment: this answer helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2032154/330606

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While there is no direct way of accessing the RequestContext, you can create one yourself:

```
RequestContext context = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)))
```

So the UrlHelper can be constructed via:

```
UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))));
```

Not pretty, but it gets the job done.

Comment: You can access the RequestContext, please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the request context using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext
```

Or, if you're in the `Global.asax` you can use

```
Context.Request.RequestContext
```

directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create an HttpContextBase from the Current HttpContext, and from that you can generate a UrlHelper:

```
// Create Http Context Base from current Context
var contextBase = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
// Get its request context
System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext = contextBase.Request.RequestContext;
// Build url helper from request context
var urlHelper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(requestContext);
```