# render Url.Action in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, model, action, render

how can i do such thing in model or controller?

```
<%= Url.Action("Home"); %>
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031995/call-urlhelper-in-models-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url.aspx) property in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string url = Url.Action("Home");
    // Do something with the url
    return View();
}
```

As far as the model is concerned you should avoid using such methods there. The model is passed to the view and the view has access to helper methods which can do the job.

Comment: do you mean UrlHelper.GenerateUrl ? but it has a lot of not clear parameters

Comment: There's a `Url` property in the controller which is of type `UrlHelper`. The same you use in your view.