# ASP.NET MVC create absolute url from c# code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do i generate an absolute url from the c# code?

I want to generate a url like this: `localhost/{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Is there a way to do it in c# like how it can be done in the views?

It wont be generated inside the controller but inside a ViewModel.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
string absUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Products", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

Just add `Request.Url.Scheme`. What this does is add a protocol to the url which forces it to generate an absolute URL.

Comment: Thanks, this was so well hidden I almost used `Url.RouteUrl`.

Comment: And if you want to generate a fully-qualified url using the Url.Action("Index") overload (where you do not specify the controller), just pass in **null** as the controller parameter. This leads to: `Url.Action("Index", null, null, Request.Url.Scheme)` .

Answer (score 1):

Check out a similar question [Using html actionlink and URL action from inside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617064/using-html-actionlink-and-url-action-from-inside-controller).  Seems to be similar and reusable for your requirements.

Comment: OP said it won't be generated inside controller but inside a viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to "build" the url and just want the full path of the current page, this will do the trick

`Context.Server.UrlEncode(Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)`

I know it's not as elegant as an Extension Method but thought of sharing it for educational purposes

Answer (score 0):

As of latest update to `MVC` you can use below `overload` for `Url.Action`

```
string url=Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", 
                       new RouteValueDictionary(new { id= someid }), 
                                                      //url param
                       HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, 
                       HttpContext.Request.Url.Host);
```

which generates

```
http://localhost:port/Controller/ActionName?id=someid
```