# in asp.net-mvc controller, what is the best way to generate a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, urlhelper

right now i take the

```
 RequestContext
```

and pass this into a UrlHelper like this:

```
UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(context);
string hrSyncUrl = u.Action("Update", "Person");
```

but the issue is that this seems to return:

```
/Person/Update
```

instead of:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Person/Update
```

so, given a controller and and action name, how can i generate a FULL url from inside a controller?

the reason that i need this is that i am generating an email so i need the full url to put in the body of that email.

Comment: What are you hoping to use it for?

Comment: @R0MANARMY  - i updated the question, i need to put a url into an email and "/Person/Update" doesn't really work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [proper overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232.aspx):

```
string hrSyncUrl = u.Action("Update", "Person", null, "http");
```

And to avoid hardcoding the protocol you could fetch it from the request:

```
var protocol = context.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;
string hrSyncUrl = u.Action("Update", "Person", null, protocol);
```

Answer (score 0):

see [ASP.NET MVC create absolute url from c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293801/asp-net-mvc-create-absolute-url-from-c-code)