# Need UrlHelper inside global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to set up a bunch of paths and URLs when my app starts, ie in `global.asax`. Using `UrlHelper.Content()` is the easiest way to do that, but it is not available for use.

So how can I get an instance of it inside `global.asax`? I tried creating one, but of course `RequestContext` doesn't exist.

The answer most linked-to is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031995/call-urlhelper-in-models-in-asp-net-mvc/2032257#2032257) but that throws exceptions for me. I am using the latest MVC3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that you have linked to doesn't work for you because you are probably running your application in IIS 7 Integrated Mode (in contrast to Classic Mode). In integrated mode you have no access to the HttpContext in `Application_Start`. So if on all price you need to generate urls in your `Application_Start` method forget about `UrlHelper`, you will need some other method. This being said you could of course use this code in events like `Application_BeginRequest`, ...

And by the way it's strange that you need to generate urls there. I have never had such need. Maybe you could explain your scenario in more details in order to get a more adapted solution to it.

Comment: I am running IIS Express on a dev machine. When we launch it will be in shared hosting. What are the implications? Do you mean I should look for a different way to solve the problem?

Comment: @merom4, IIS Express configures by default Integrated Mode which explains why your code doesn't work. I don't know what is your scenario nor why you need to generate url, nor where/in which method precisely. So I cannot give you more specific answer.

Comment: In summary, I have a static class with all sorts of urls and paths to external resources, images, logs, etc. And when the app starts I need to set some stuff in there, like the app root.

Comment: If I cant access UrlHelper, my question I guess is, given some absolute path, how can I convert it to a relative one so I can serve it... for eg "/blah/blah/mysite/images/image.png" to "/images/image.png"?

Comment: @merom4, you will have to find some alternative method to initialize those values, not in Application_Start. As I said you don't have access to the HttpContext if you run in Integrated Mode. Also what you have shown in your comment are two relative paths.