# Get Action URL inside MVC4 .NET class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Basically, I want the same functionality as Url.Action, but outside of the controller. Is this possible?

While I'm sure I'll use it elsewhere, my current desire is to generate action url's inside of a viewmodel.

Comment: Create your own extension method just by appending strings together..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call UrlHelper in models in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031995/call-urlhelper-in-models-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can instantiate a `UrlHelper` in your view model, like so:

```
UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```

Then, you can use this just like the one you use in your view:

```
string actionUrl = helper.Action("MyAction", "MyController");
```

Comment: I [just read here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582207/1037948) that you want to avoid using `HttpContext.Current` -- not sure if that's applicable here, or even possible.

Comment: @drzaus this is not ASP.NET Web API, so no, it's not applicable here.