# Add link in the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3, i am passing some url in the string type property,
for this i have used

```
var uri = new UrlHelper().Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

But it is giving error. which is

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: routeCollection"}

i know **.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);** has four parameters but i only want to pass two, what will be the default value for it??

Comment: I have also tried this but still it is giving error "{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: routeCollection"}"
var uri = new UrlHelper().Action("Actionname", "ControllerName", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Id = 4}));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i searched it and found the answer.
[Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031995/call-urlhelper-in-models-in-asp-net-mvc)

var uri = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");

It is working fine after adding **HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext**.

Answer (score 3):

If you're inside your `Controller`, you use the static `Url.Action()`instead, and it will work:

```
var uri = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

And if you're outside of a `Controller`(e.g in your `Model`) you have to use the `UrlHelper` as you did, but passing a Context in parameter, so the method can make the correct url for you.

You can get the request context in this way:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext
```

So, if you can use it like this:

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var uri = url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

Comment: I know about it. But this time I'm using it in a model to make a string. That's why I am using it in this way...